# What are the correct parameters for Magento Product Attribute creation in Perl

Tags: perl, magento, xml-rpc

I've got several calls working already, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to make `product_attribute.create` work. I'm always getting a `102 Invalid request parameters` or `623 Wrong Method Signature`.

making the call like this `my $res = $self->_useragent->call( call => $self->_session, @{$payload} );` (note: useragent is a [XML::RPC](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aRPC) object.

This `Dumper $payload`;

```
 $VAR1 = [
      'product_attribute.create',
      [
        'test',
        {
          'frontend_label' => [
                                {
                                  'label' => 'Test ME',
                                  'store_id' => 0
                                }
                              ],
          'scope' => 'store',
          'frontend_input' => 'text'
        }
      ]
    ];
```

I've read the [API Documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/product_attribute.update.html) but figuring out what the call should look like in Perl is tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging through Magento's code, I copied this from the test suite and it converted to perl, it appears to work. maybe all attributes are required.

```
$VAR1 = [
      'product_attribute.create',
      [
        {
          'default_value' => '1',
          'is_configurable' => 0,
          'used_in_product_listing' => 0,
          'is_visible_on_front' => 0,
          'apply_to' => [
                          'simple'
                        ],
          'is_comparable' => 0,
          'is_used_for_promo_rules' => 0,
          'is_required' => 0,
          'scope' => 'store',
          'is_unique' => 0,
          'frontend_input' => 'text',
          'is_searchable' => 0,
          'attribute_code' => 'unique_code',
          'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
          'frontend_label' => [
                                {
                                  'label' => 'some label',
                                  'store_id' => '0'
                                }
                              ]
        }
      ]
    ];
```

Further experimentation somewhat based on [Alan Storm's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17767439/206466), suggest that the following fields are required, as I was not able to successfully create a request without all of these fields at minimum being defined.

```
 $VAR1 = [
      'product_attribute.create',
      [
        {
          'frontend_input' => 'text',
          'attribute_code' => 'test1374438470',
          'frontend_label' => [
                                {
                                  'store_id' => 0,
                                  'label' => 'Test ME'
                                }
                              ]
        }
      ]
    ];
```

Comment: Answered below (or above).  You don't need all the attributes/properties, you were just missing the attribute_code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the XML-RPC library you're using in perl, but he error you're seeing is a Magento API exception, configured in

```
<!--File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/api.xml -->
<!-- ... -->
<invalid_parameters>
    <code>102</code>
    <message>Invalid request parameters.</message>
</invalid_parameters>    
<!-- ... -->
```

Using the exception's name, you can find the place Magento threw it

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Api.php
//...
if (empty($data['attribute_code']) || !is_array($data['frontend_label'])) {
    $this->_fault('invalid_parameters');
}
//...
```

So, my guess is your call is correct, you're just missing an `attribute_code`.

Comment: I could swear I had tried this in some iteration... but I must have had it slightly different. (my original call put attribute code as the first element of the arrayref which at least one of the examples in the docs suggest it correct. ). If you wouldn't mind copying my data structure to your answer I could accept it (since the actual structure is important)